# elasticsearch aggregation bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In Kibana (or potentially even elasticsearch), is there a way to sort documents into buckets based on a field, and then compute statistics on the generated buckets themselves? Here is a simplified example of my problem:

I have logs with structure:

```
{
    user_id: [string],
    post_id: [string]
}
```

that signal a user with ID `user_id` has viewed post with ID `post_id`. I would like to:

1. bucket the logs by matching `user_id`
2. Count the amount of logs per bucket
3. Compute the 75th percentile of these bucket-specific counts

Is this possible in Kibana?